# Where can I find Scholia Arcana in Rathir?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I know I can buy a backpack from someone in here but I can't actually find it in Rathir. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scholia Arcana is in the upper city of Rathir. When you first enter the city, you'll need to run to the other end and up some steps to get to the upper city. From there, you can get to the Scholia Arcana. Once in the upper city, it should show up on your map.

[image]

[image]